# Adding multiple markers to a Mapbox Map on android, cannot add source to mapboxMap

Tags: android, mapbox

following this tutorial [SymbolLayer](https://blog.mapbox.com/a-guide-to-the-android-symbollayer-api-5daac7b66f2c) I have a created a geoJson String from a list of objects that I get from my database. When I need to call

```
mapboxMap.addSource(source);
```

I cannot find an addSource method for my map. Nor the addLayer one. What I went ahead and do is inside my onMapReady method called style.addSource and style.addLayer, but it didn't work. here's what it looks like:

```
public void onMapReady(@NonNull final MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
    MainActivity.this.mapboxMap = mapboxMap;
    Drawable drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_fuel_11, null);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapUtils.getBitmapFromDrawable(drawable); 
  //got the image to display
    String geoJsonData = toJson(getDistr()); 
  //got the geoJson String
    FeatureCollection featureCollection = FeatureCollection.fromJson(geoJsonData);
    Source source = new GeoJsonSource("id", featureCollection);
    SymbolLayer symbolLayer = new SymbolLayer("layerId", "id");

    mapboxMap.setStyle(new Style.Builder().fromUri("mapbox://styles/mapbox/navigation-preview-day-v4"),
            new Style.OnStyleLoaded() {
                @Override
                public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {
                    style.addImage("img", bitmap);
                    style.addSource(source);
                    style.addLayer(symbolLayer.withProperties(PropertyFactory.iconImage("img")));
                    enableLocationComponent(style);
                }
            });
```

Anyone can say what I am doing wrong, or what other aproach I should take to displaying a list of objects I have in my DB with Latitude and Longitude into the map?

Comment: Did my answer below get your project working correctly?

Comment: I had managed to get it working it already,  moving the code to onStyleLoaded like you also suggested, so yes. Thank you!

Comment: Great, glad ya' figured it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/marker-symbol-layer/

Try moving the following code to the `onStyleLoaded()` callback rather than `onMapReady()`. Try running it before the `style.addImage("img", bitmap);` line.

```
MainActivity.this.mapboxMap = mapboxMap;
    Drawable drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_fuel_11, null);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapUtils.getBitmapFromDrawable(drawable); 
  //got the image to display
    String geoJsonData = toJson(getDistr()); 
  //got the geoJson String
    FeatureCollection featureCollection = FeatureCollection.fromJson(geoJsonData);
    Source source = new GeoJsonSource("id", featureCollection);
    SymbolLayer symbolLayer = new SymbolLayer("layerId", "id");
```